# ASP.NET Role Manager Feature Has Not Been Enabled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, membership, roleprovider

I'm trying to create a routine in my asp.net's main page that will see if the current user is a member of a Windows domain group. The site is hosted in IIS and is visible through our intranet.

GlenFerrieLive listed this code (which I'd like to use) in an earlier post:

```
    UserName = System.Environment.UserName

    If Roles.IsUserInRole(UserName, "MyDomain\MyGroup") Then
        Dim UserExists As Boolean = True
    End If
```

When trying that code, I got the above-mentioned error. So I plugged in the roleManager tag in my Web.config like so:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="480" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All" />
```

Problem is, now I'm getting the configuration error 'Default Role Provider could not be found'.

How can I get around this? I just need to see if the current user exists in a specific domain group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
Private Function ValidateActiveDirectoryLogin(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    Dim Entry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & Domain, Username, Password)
    Dim Searcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(Entry)
    Searcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.OneLevel
    Try
        Dim Results As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult = Searcher.FindOne
        Success = Not (Results Is Nothing)
    Catch
        Success = False
    End Try
    Return Success
End Function
```

Worked like a charm when this was in my web.config:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>

    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="480" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into this page:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

You need something like this in your webconfig specifying where the default role provider points to

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" 
   connectionString=
    "LDAP://domain.testing.com/CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=testing,DC=com" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
 ...
 <membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="MembershipADProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, 
            Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
                connectionUsername="<domainName>\administrator" 
                connectionPassword="password"/>
   </providers>
 </membership>
 ...
</system.web>
```